# VIM with Vundle is adding the letter 'g' to random areas of the .vimrc

Tags: vim, youcompleteme, vundle

I keep editing the file and removing the random letter 'g's but they keep re-appearing and of course this generates errors when starting VIM.

Anyone know why this would occur?

[image]

Comment: Your system seems to be host to extra `g`s.  I assume you run this from a shell?  There might be a g-host in the shell.  I'll see myself out.

Comment: Well, when I run it from tmux the issue goes away, so I guess shell or terminal or whatever definitely has something to do with it.  I'm always using tmux so I guess I'm good.